# How to establish relationships between Hashtags using PHP / MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, api, instagram

I'm working on a tool in PHP that scans Instagram to gather analytics on a bunch of hashtags. The aim is to monitor the evolution / growth of certain hashtags and provide a search engine for people to get up to date statistics on each hashtag.

So far I've got a fairly simple search engine in place, and I run a a SQL query that looks for `LIKE %'travel'%`. So if someone types "#travel", they'll get anything that contains the world "travel" such as "travelagent" "iliketotravel", etc.

The issue I'm facing is I'd like to broaden the search results to include things that are *related* to #travel, much like websites like http://displaypurposes.com or http://best-hashtags.com/ and I'm trying to figure out just HOW they do it.

I'm especially fascinated by the first one, and the Graph function: https://displaypurposes.com/graph?tag=travel

It looks like they've effectively mapped all the links between a huge number of hashtags and provide results based on that.

I have about 45 000 hashtags in my database, how would I go about linking them together to enable a "relevancy search" like the two websites I mentioned above? How does one go about building something similar? I've spent ages looking online and can't find the answer to my question.

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a programming question but I'll try answer it in a way that addresses it in such a way.

It's possible to have multiple tags on a single Instagram post. For example, you might have someone posting a picture of Rome with the hashtags `#rome` `#travel`. This now associates `#rome` with `#travel` and counts this as a connection between the two.

As long as we have a table structure with the following attributes:

- PostNumber
- Hashtag

We can find the top relations by running something like the following code:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) `Relation Occurances`, 
        b.Hashtag
FROM 
    Posts a
JOIN 
    Posts b
ON 
    a.PostNumber = b.PostNumber
WHERE 
    a.Hashtag = '#travel'
AND 
    b.Hashtag != '#travel'
```

You can refine the query to limit to 100 top relations and so on if required.

To further expand on this, the key is splitting the post out into a table with 1 row per post per hashtag. If you're doing wildcard searches on large text, this will lead to long processing times and be inefficient.

Comment: So it really is a question of building a table for each relationship? So, for example every time I scan the hashtag #travel for results I also store a row in a table for every occurrence of another hashtag that was in posts under #travel, and then use that new table to identify the top relationships between tags.

I'm just concerned this might lead to massive tables, and I thought there might be a better way, but it seems like this might be the only realistic solution?

Comment: I would highly suggest having a table with the relevant instagram `postid` and each hashtag in a separate row. It's all about putting your data in a format which you can easily query. That may require a bit of extra time on the PHP side, but that is what you have to do to get it into a decent format. In regards to having large databases, as long as they are structured correctly and configured right, it shouldn't be a problem. I've had MySQL tables with billions of rows query fine. If you're just storing the full post in text, that will mean a lot of processing every time you want to query it.